# Javascript callback method not updating AngularJS unless in shorthand form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, methods, shorthand

In the following two snippets embedded inside an angular controller for logging in a user (taken from [angular-meteor tutorial](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/angular-material-and-custom-angular-auth-forms)):

```
    this.login = function() {
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(this.credentials.email, this.credentials.password, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                this.error = err.reason;
            }
            else {
                $state.go('index');
            }
        });
    };
```

and:

```
    this.login = function() {
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(this.credentials.email, this.credentials.password, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                this.error = err.reason;
            }
            else {
                $state.go('index');
            }
        });
    };
```

The first causes AngularJS to update the value of error after the callback but the second snippet doesnt trigger an update. The only difference is the use of the shorthand method declaration in the first one. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Please ass script how you invoking this function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't just *shorthand*, the first uses an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).  Arrow functions treat their scope differently than a `function` lambda.

Arrow functions inherit their parent scope.  So, there is no need to bind `this` inside (for this example).

If you use a `function` lambda, you must `bind` `this`:

```
this.login = function() {
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(this.credentials.email, this.credentials.password, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                this.error = err.reason;
            }
            else {
                $state.go('index');
            }
        }.bind(this));
    };
```